# Fortin Operator for Crouzeix-Raviart Element

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I want to prove the LBB condition for the Stokes Equations discretised by the Crouzeix-Raviart element.

The continuous Stokes Equation in the weak formulation is

> Find $u \in H_0^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ and $p \in L_0^2(\Omega)$ with
>
> \begin{align} \int_\Omega \nabla u : \nabla v dx - \int_\Omega
>  p \text{ div} (v) dx &= \int_{\Omega} fv dx \qquad \ \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)\\ 
>  \int_\Omega q \text{ div} (u) dx&= 0 \qquad \qquad \quad \forall q \in
>  L_0^2(\Omega) \end{align}

It has a unique solution in the spaces $V = H_0^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ and $Q= L_0^2(\Omega)$.

For the discrete spaces I have

\begin{align}
V_h &= \{ v_h \in H_0^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d) : v_h|_T\in P^3(T),v_h|_E\in P^2(E),\forall T \in T_h\forall E\subset \partial T\}\\
Q_h &= \{q_h\in L_0^1(\Omega):q_h|_T\in P^1(T),\forall T \in T_h \}
\end{align}

To prove solvability, I want to prove the discrete LBB condition

\begin{align}
\sup\limits_{v_h\in V_h} \frac{\int_\Omega \text{div}(v_h)q_h dx}{\|v_h\|_{V}} \geq \beta_1 \|q_h\|_{Q} \qquad \forall q_h \in Q_h
\end{align}

For the continuous spaces $V,Q$ the LBB condition holds.

Assume there exists a Fortin operator $\Pi_h:V \rightarrow V_h$ with
\begin{align}
\|\Pi_h v \|_V &\preccurlyeq \|v\|_V \qquad \quad \forall v\in V \\
b(\Pi_h v, q_h) &= b(v, q_h) \qquad \ \forall q_h \in Q_h
\end{align}
Then the continuous LBB implies the discrete LBB.

> Can you please tell me how I can construct such an Fortin Operator and then prove its two properties.
>
> Especially it would be very helpful to see the full scaling argument that proves its continuity.

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: [Now, also posted at Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/35329/20688)